# Запуск программ из терминала в android 4.0.4

Tags: android

У меня телефон sony xperia sola в котором есть плеер walkman. Через диспетчер задач я его случайно отключил и он пропал отовсюду. В пакетах он есть. `pm list package Есть строка:package: com.sonyericsson.music`Пытался запустить через менеджер приложений -- не получилось. Файл нашел в /system/app/SemcMusic.apk. Пишет "Действие не найдено - com.sonyericsson.music". В подробностях есть действие com.sonyericsson.music.PlayerActivity. Я так и понял, что таким боком можно вернуть плеер обратно. Загуглил -- нашел, что приложения запускаются `am start *само приложение*` Попробовал запустить, ничего не получается. Выдает на всех приложениях (пробовал com.sonyericsson.music , com.sonyericsson.music.PlayerActivity , com.sonyericsson.notes) такую ошибку:

> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   pkg=com.sonyericsson.music.PlayerActivity }    Error: Activity not
>   started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000
>   pkg=com.sonyericsson.music.PlayerActivity }

Ошибка везде одна и та же. Ничего не меняется, если выбрать другой пакет. Или я что-то не правильно делаю?PS Ключи пробовал разные. Результата ноль.

Comment: Если сами найдёте, расскажите нам, как это удалось сделать. Оч интересно ))

Comment: @ArcherGodson эхх, а я уж на ответ понадеялся...

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать com.sonyericsson.music/.PlayerActivity. AM любит, чтобы пакет и приложение разделялись символом "/".

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать 
pm enable <название пакета>
После этого попробовать запустить его через утилиту am

Answer (score 0):

Незнаю как на старых версиях android,но на новых системное приложение запустить можно так:  am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings  (am  start -n (название пакета/.название активити)  или так:  adb shell monkey -p com.tafayor.killall 1  (пользовательское приложение)  где интерактивная оболочка adb ставиться на устройство и запускаеться в терминале termux  ( https://github.com/MasterDevX/Termux-ADB ) .После установки пакета adb подключаемся к компу и печатаем: adb tcpip 5555 .Все.Сервер adb установился на устройство.
PS  после перезагрузки adb оболочка слетает и нужно заново подключаться к компу.